# Implement approval and disapproval of users using Membership in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a sample using `MVC 5` and for authentication I am using Membership. I found `MVC 5` `Membership` very different from Membership we use with ASP.NET Web Formns. I am a beginner in MVC and  facing hard time to understand it.

The table generated for user have only 5 columns as below:

```
    [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Discriminator] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
```

I am able to find proper `Membership` methods to perform operations for `Application User`. Please explain the new structure and suggest the solution to approve and disapprove any user.

Comment: You don't have to switch to the new authentication framework. MVC will work with the old, good membership/role providers you had experience from your Web.Forms development.

Comment: you can see there are build in method for check whether user is approved or not

Comment: The sample project that you create from VS, has an account registration and log on/off done, you can check the code for a basic understanding.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I tried that with database first approach .. but I dont know how to create IdentityUser on my own so I stuck at initial phase (login, registration)

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee where I can find those methods .. as activehigh is suggesting, I have gone through the default code in InternetApplication of MVC but the methods were not so useful. I don't even found a method to get username by user id.

Comment: for these method you need to implement your own repositories